# ng style function and inline together

Tags: angularjs

How can I setup ng-style to accept a scope method and some inline styles. So it would look something like

```
ng-style="{'background': someColorCode}; getPosition()"
```

In this instance an error is thrown with unexpected token :

Is there a correct syntax?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
ng-style="{'background': someColorCode, 'position': getPosition() }"
```

Where your `getPosition` function returns valid position style value (absolute, static, fixed, ...) for example.

```
$scope.getPosition = function () {
     //your position logic
     return 'absolute';
}
```